# Earliest printed record of the phrase "in the blink of an eye"?

Tags: etymology, phrase-origin, origin-unknown

I cannot trace the origin of the phrase "in the blink of an eye," neither the earliest printed record of the expression.

Surprisingly, even the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+blink+of+an+eye&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=) returns a "NO" result. How come?

Comment: [Here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blink+of+an+eye&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblink%20of%20an%20eye%3B%2Cc0) the NGram chart for 'blink of an eye'.

Comment: Did you look at what Ngram said about your entry???

Comment: As @HotLicks said, it returns a "NO" result because your input was more than five words. Try "[*the blink of an eye*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+blink+of+an+eye&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=5)". The earliest instance you'll be able to see is 1714.

Comment: @Justin - did you find a 1714 usage? Can you please provide the specific link because I can’t find earlier usage instances of 1874.

Comment: @user66974 - That being said, I'm not sure if there is a 1714 usage... Ngram might be showing the words "blink" and "eye" as two separate instances... However, the origin of the idiom stems from "in the *twinkling* of an eye" as you've mentioned below. The word "blink" itself originated in 1578.. but I'm not sure if "*in the blink of an eye*" was put into use until after the 1800s.

Comment: @Justin , I only find 1874.

Comment: However, I did find another usage before 1874, although, it makes use of the word "winking". "*The buck , however , disappeared in the **winking** of her eye , like the puck , demon , or rushlight friar , which she supposed him to be ; but appalled by all around her , and bewildered which way to turn , she sat down in despair at the foot of the ...*" in [1848](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=JOEpAQAAIAAJ&q=the+blink+of+an+eye&dq=the+blink+of+an+eye&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiB8dvwqJ7vAhWXgtgFHRFGDkI4HhDoATAAegQIBRAC)

Comment: Here's another one in [1840](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=12tAAQAAMAAJ&q=the+blink+of+an+eye&dq=the+blink+of+an+eye&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwityKifqJ7vAhW27XMBHaiiAf4Q6AEwB3oECAcQAg) - "*Her mother next morning , by the **blink of her eye** , Betwixt her and Grigor great love did espy , And she to her husband the same soon revealed , Giving orders to watch them as they're in the field , All day then her father went looking about ...*". I wasn't able to access the preview though. This is from the search result that shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In the blink of an eye](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/in-the-blink-of-an-eye) is a later version of the much older similar expression “[In the twinkling of an eye](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/in-the-twinkling-of-an-eye)”, which, as the [Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/202400.html) notes:

> It is recorded by Robert Manning of Brunne, in Handlyng synne, 1303: *"Yn twynkelyng of an ye"*

> It is also used in the Bible, 1 Corinthians 15:52 (King James Version):
> *In a moment, in the twinkling of an eye, at the last trump: for the trumpet shall sound, and the dead shall be raised incorruptible, and we shall be changed.*

> It was later used by Shakespeare in The Merchant Of Venice, 1596:
> *"I'll take my leave of the Jew in the twink of an eye”*

As you can see from [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blink%20of%20an%20eye%2Ctwinkling%20of%20an%20eye&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblink%20of%20an%20eye%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwinkling%20of%20an%20eye%3B%2Cc0) “In the blink of an eye” emerged in the second half of the  19th c. and, apparently, is now [the more commonly used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blink%20of%20an%20eye%2Ctwinkling%20of%20an%20eye&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblink%20of%20an%20eye%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwinkling%20of%20an%20eye%3B%2Cc0).

An early usage example is from
[Chambers's Edinburgh journal of Popular Literature](https://books.google.it/books?id=9UAFAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA397&dq=%22blink%20of%20an%20eye%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjwzp2x5J3vAhUCzaQKHR59BdIQ6AEwCXoECAUQAw#v=onepage&q=%22blink%20of%20an%20eye%22&f=false) conducted by W. Chambers, 1874:

> She 's that quick, she was gone like the blink of an eye ; and, besides, Jenny, she is not one to be easily hindered when she 's set upon a thing.

And from [A Cook Book](https://books.google.it/books?id=aLpEAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA5&dq=%22blink%20of%20an%20eye%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiP_I25553vAhUPPuwKHZ1uAU4Q6AEwBnoECAcQAw#v=onepage&q=%22blink%20of%20an%20eye%22&f=false), 1876:

> Ho ! all ye poor sinners , in search of good dinners , You'll surely be winners , if our plan you will try ; Only just take a look in this wise little book , And ' twill teach you to cook in the blink of an eye.

Comment: About the Bible verse I found this: 'This is translated from the Greek phrase en rhipē opthalmou, which most literally means "flicking the eye" and was the ancient reference to "the blink of an eye'. Interesting that most modern versions have kept _twinkling_ rather than _blink_, despite the rather different connotations of 'a twinkle _in_ the eye'.